# Change an element's visibility after specified action

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm going to make something like a form with following feature: when you load a webpage, you'll see only one element like:

1. Choose sex:

   - male
   - female

and when you choose for example "male" (radio button), suddenly, but with some smooth effect, next element will appear below:
2. enter your score:
**TEXTBOX HERE**
and when you enter the score, at least (1 numerical sign), the final element, submit button will appear below element number 2.

How can I achieve this? Maybe you know any already done solutions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would have to use javascript.

Comment: you can use slideDown Jquery function on click of radio button.....@macieg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make `visiblity hidden(display:none)` of all elements of a form except male
female radio buttons and then do something like this :-

```
$("#radio").click(function(){
  $("#txt").show();
});

$("#txt").blur(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).val())!="")
  {
    $("#btn").show();
  }
});
```